# How to amplify without contact a 10-20Khz square signal?

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design

I would like to amplify a square signal 50% PWM on a live wire, the wire carry also  a sine wave 60Hz at 120VAC.

The square signal will be only present a a few milliseconds after the zero cross.

Like in this example, but instead of 120kHz I will be using 10 to 20kHz:

[image]

Since they are two signals on the wire; a sine wave at 60hz and 120V, and a square wave 50pwm, on the zero crossing.

How discriminate the sinewave and amplify just the square wave?.

My goal is to make something like a non contact detector "wand".
[image: They are quite simple.]

But they collect the 60Hz signal for the amplification.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please realise that this is not a free design
house or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied
out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question
shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your
post doesn't, I'm afraid. What you are asking for is a complete system design.  I am also worried that you want to work with line voltages but do not know how to filter a 10KHz signal. Please revise your question showing your work and
findings so far, in considerable detail. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: I like to post as much information I have on a concrete issue, but my two first questions were suspended on the lack of concrete topic. Your comment open a window tomorrow I will post more detail on this, the main idea, the readings already doing etc. Thanks again. -Alex.

Comment: The question is unclear: you want to inject a signal or to amplify a signal already present ? Also, what is the aim of this circuit ? from where does this come from?

Comment: why can't you use an X capacitor?

Comment: The idea is to make a two parts wire signal tracer; "the injector" make 4 different singal 10, 20, 30 and 50kHz, each of witch will be in a separate channel.

Comment: The "detector" must sniff this signal and differentiate from the others, being a 60Hz inmune is necessary for avoid "reading" the frequency of the mains AC. Oh almost forgeth, I will use this on lice AC wire.